# Django: querying multiple types of objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a fairly basic model that allows users to create posts of different 'types'. There's currently a Text type and a Photo type that inherits from a base '`Post`' type.

I'm currently pulling `TextPosts` and `PhotoPosts` and chaining the two QuerySets, but this seems like a bad idea.

Is there a way to simply query for both types of posts at once? The reason I'm not using `.filter()` on `Post` itself is because I (presumably) don't have any way of getting the `TextPost` or `PhotoPost` object from it (or do I?)

PS: Does it make more sense to call it BasePost or Post if I'll never be using Post by itself?

```
class Post(AutoDateTimeModel):
    POST_TYPES = (
        # Linkable Social Networks
        ('TEXT', 'Text'),
        ('PHOTO', 'Photo'),
        ('LINK', 'Link'),
    )

    post_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interest, related_name='interests')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'posts'
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.post_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TextPost(Post):
    """ Text post model """
    body = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'posts'

class PhotoPost(Post):
    """ Photo post model. This can contain multiple photos. """
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'posts'

class Photo(models.Model):
    """ Individual image model, used in photo posts. """
    caption = models.TextField()
    # source_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = ImageField(upload_to=upload_to)
    post = models.ForeignKey(PhotoPost, blank=True, null=True, related_name='photos')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='photos')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'posts'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Photo Object by: ' + str(self.user.get_full_name())
```

Comment: `TextPost` and `PhotoPost` are two different tables underneath your ORM classes. You cannot get both tables at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this nice app [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils), using InheritanceManager in your Post class.

A nice example from the docs:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Place(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()

class Restaurant(Place):
    # ...

class Bar(Place):
    # ...

nearby_places = Place.objects.filter(location='here').select_subclasses()
for place in nearby_places:
    # "place" will automatically be an instance of Place, Restaurant, or Bar
```

Applying for your situation:

```
class Post(AutoDateTimeModel):
    ...
    objects = InheritanceManager()


class TextPost(Post):
    ...

class PhotoPost(Post):
    ...
```

And this answers your question: Is there a way to simply query for both types of posts at once?

You can query for posts now, resulting instances of TextPost and Photoposts